# ROS minimal installation

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is there a preferred method for doing a minimal installation (smaller than ros-base)... such that the robot would be more of an embedded target and the development environment would be some logical setup (some VM).

I'm working with a com-express board with an atom processor and a 4GB hard drive. I'm trying to get the install as compact as possible. Any thoughts (even a different direction than the "embedded target") would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12816/ros-minimal-installation/) by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you explored [eros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros)?

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on 2012-01-31**:
looking into it now. thanks.